# Given an ellipse's center, focus and point, find its equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

Given an ellipse's center is $(2,1)$, focus is (2,4) and point is (3,-3), we have

Plug in center:

$\frac{(x-2)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-1)^2}{b^2} = 1$

Use focus:

$4^2=a^2-b^2$

$16=a^2-b^2$

Use point:

$\frac{(3-2)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(-3-1)^2}{b^2} = 1$

$\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{16}{b^2} = 1$

$b^2+16a^2 = a^2b^2$

Is this right?

Combine equations:

$b^2+16a^2 = a^2b^2$

$16=a^2-b^2$

So, we have:

$0 = b^2 - b^2 - 16^2$

$b^2 = \frac{1}{2} (1+5 \sqrt{41})$

and

$a^2 = 16 + \frac{1}{2} (1+5 \sqrt{41})$

Comment: If in doubt, ask Wolfram Alpha. In this case, your answer is wrong: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-2%29%5E2%2F%2816%2B0.5%281%2B5*sqrt%2841%29%29%29%2B%28y-1%29%5E2%2F%280.5%281%2B5*sqrt%2841%29%29%29%3D1

(Click properties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong. The answer is $\frac{(x-2)^2}{9}+\frac{(y-1)^2}{18}=1$. Thanks for the WolframAlpha suggestion, @alexqwx . I never knew WA could do that.